# Como somar itens de uma coluna no SQL

Tags: sql

Gostaria de saber como somar esses itens repetidos totalizando a quantidade deles,
sou iniciante em SQL

select Cardapio.IndicadorSetor, AtendimentoItem.Quantidade
from Cardapio,AtendimentoItem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esse SQL soma as quantidades agrupando os itens:

```
select Cardapio.IndicadorSetor, Cardapio.NomeItem, SUM(AtendimentoItem.Quantidade)
from Cardapio,AtendimentoItem 
group by Cardapio.IndicadorSetor, Cardapio.NomeItem
```

Comment: Deu certo, valeu